# How to use selected layers code in my script?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

With following photoshop script i can remove active selection from all layers. now i want to edit it and change from "all layers" to "selected layers only". how to do this?

```
// 2023, use at your own risk;
if (app.documents.length > 0) {
    var theLayers = collectLayersNamesIndexAndIdentifier ();
    for (var m = 0; m < theLayers.length; m++) {
        selectLayerByID (theLayers[m][2], false);
        try {activeDocument.selection.clear()}
        catch (e) {}
        }
    };
////// collect layers //////
function collectLayersNamesIndexAndIdentifier () {
// the file;
var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
// get number of layers;
var ref = new ActionReference();
ref.putProperty(stringIDToTypeID('property'), stringIDToTypeID('numberOfLayers'));
ref.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID("Dcmn"), charIDToTypeID("Ordn"), charIDToTypeID("Trgt") ); 
var applicationDesc = executeActionGet(ref);
var theNumber = applicationDesc.getInteger(stringIDToTypeID("numberOfLayers"));
// process the layers;
var theLayers = new Array;
for (var m = 0; m <= theNumber; m++) {
try {
var ref = new ActionReference();
ref.putIndex( charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " ), m);
var layerDesc = executeActionGet(ref);
var layerSet = typeIDToStringID(layerDesc.getEnumerationValue(stringIDToTypeID("layerSection")));
var isBackground = layerDesc.getBoolean(stringIDToTypeID("background"));
// if group collect values;
if (layerSet != "layerSectionEnd" && layerSet != "layerSectionStart" && isBackground != true) {
var theName = layerDesc.getString(stringIDToTypeID('name'));
var theID = layerDesc.getInteger(stringIDToTypeID('layerID'));
var theIndex = layerDesc.getInteger(stringIDToTypeID('itemIndex'));
theLayers.push([theName, theIndex, theID])
};
}
catch (e) {};
};
return theLayers
};
////// based on code by mike hale, via paul riggott //////
function selectLayerByID(id,add){ 
add = undefined ? add = false:add 
var ref = new ActionReference();
    ref.putIdentifier(charIDToTypeID("Lyr "), id);
    var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc.putReference(charIDToTypeID("null"), ref );
        if(add) desc.putEnumerated( stringIDToTypeID( "selectionModifier" ), stringIDToTypeID( "selectionModifierType" ), stringIDToTypeID( "addToSelection" ) ); 
        desc.putBoolean( charIDToTypeID( "MkVs" ), false ); 
    try{
    executeAction(charIDToTypeID("slct"), desc, DialogModes.NO );
}catch(e){
}
};
```

**note that I'm not a programmer and only use ready photoshop scripts to edit my images.**

**In the past I have been told that in order to run the script on the selected layers I should use the following code in the desired script:**

```
#target photoshop

/* Start Process selected layers - from jazz-y */
var s2t = stringIDToTypeID;
(r = new ActionReference()).putProperty(s2t('property'), p = s2t('targetLayersIDs'));
r.putEnumerated(s2t('document'), s2t('ordinal'), s2t('targetEnum'));
var lrs = executeActionGet(r).getList(p),
    sel = new ActionReference();

for (var i = 0; i < lrs.count; i++) {
    sel.putIdentifier(s2t('layer'), p = lrs.getReference(i).getIdentifier(s2t('layerID')));
    (r = new ActionReference()).putIdentifier(s2t('layer'), p);
    (d = new ActionDescriptor()).putReference(s2t("target"), r);
    executeAction(s2t('select'), d, DialogModes.NO);
/* End Process selected layers - from jazz-y */

// Your code here:
alert(activeDocument.activeLayer.name);

}
```

**but i don't know how to use and replace this code in my script** because i'm not a programmer.
please help me to edit this script.

Answer (score -1):

following is answer:

```
#target photoshop

/* Check for selection - from jazz-y */
var selectionBounds = null;
try {
    selectionBounds = activeDocument.selection.bounds
} catch (e) {}
if (selectionBounds) {

        /* Start Process selected layers - from jazz-y */
        var s2t = stringIDToTypeID;
        (r = new ActionReference()).putProperty(s2t('property'), p = s2t('targetLayersIDs'));
        r.putEnumerated(s2t('document'), s2t('ordinal'), s2t('targetEnum'));
        var lrs = executeActionGet(r).getList(p),
            sel = new ActionReference();
        for (var i = 0; i < lrs.count; i++) {
            sel.putIdentifier(s2t('layer'), p = lrs.getReference(i).getIdentifier(s2t('layerID')));
            (r = new ActionReference()).putIdentifier(s2t('layer'), p);
            (d = new ActionDescriptor()).putReference(s2t("target"), r);
            executeAction(s2t('select'), d, DialogModes.NO);
        /* End Process selected layers - from jazz-y */

        /* Clear selected layers */
        try {
            activeDocument.selection.clear()
        } catch (e) {}
    }

} else {
    alert("This script requires a selection!");
}
```